# How to draw gradient with custom equation in CALayer or CGContext in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, core-graphics, core-animation

I want to draw a linear gradient in different colorspace in iOS device with `CoreAnimation` or `CoreGraphics`. However, I found that `CAGradientLayer`(Linear gradient) only draws linear in device colorspace sense, and also alpha addition is considered in device colorspace. Specifically, I want to simulate another gamma correction. Is there anyway to give custom gamma curve to the gradient?

Moreover, the ultimate objective is to make it animatable. (E.g. define gamma animatable property on `CALayer`.) Any related idea is okay. I could not find discussions about this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exact syntax for objective c but I can help u in swift.

Here I created an extension for a view to show gradient effect.

```
extension UIView {
func layerGradient() {

 let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradient.colors = [UIColor.UIColorFromRGB(fromHex: 0x26344b).cgColor, UIColor.UIColorFromRGB(fromHex: 0x30bdb7).cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: self.frame.size.height)


    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in this case, the gradient is linear, right? linear in gamma 2.2 sense (system default) by what ever means. Simply speaking, I don't want linear gradient but with some function. I thought simulating it with multiple middle points consumes too much resources.